# Ubuntu server 20.04 not able to update

Tags: networking, apt, server, 20.04, ubuntu-website

I just installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on an older HP bare metal server.  I had to update the resolv.conf file under systemd but now I can ping archive.ubuntu.com.  I can even nslookup them and get a resolution for the dns name.  It looks like I am definitely getting out.

I am unable to do an apt-get update as it always comes back and says it could not connect to the network. Does anyone have an idea what could be going on?

The Firewall is not on either of my computers either. I have a desktop pc running the same Ubuntu server in virtualbox that is unable to update unless it is running in NAT network mode. When I run it as Bridged network mode it can't update.

```
# apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

```
~$ nslookup archive.ubuntu.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.88.152
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.88.142
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23
```

```
~$ ping archive.ubuntu.com
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=131 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=131 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=131 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=131 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=131 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=131 ms
```

Comment: Put your output in http://pastebin.ubuntu.com, and add the link to your question.

Comment: Thank you Nmath, I was trying to figure out how to set it and didn't see the ```'s anywhere.  I added them and it didn't spaz out about it being spam this time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with our network.  If a windows computer is a fresh install it has the same issues as with the Ubuntu systems.  It can ping, and resolve domain names but no http activity.  I don't know what the settings are but when the windows system is added to the Active Directory domain in our network it is allowed to reach the internet if it isn't connected then it can't.  There are no proxies on the firewall or the local windows machines so I'm not sure what is stopping it.  I'm still trying to find out what settings are causing this.  The firewall is open for this system's IP so it is something in the Windows AD world and the network services like DHCP and DNS that are managed by Windows services.